# Import EmguCV in Python failed

Tags: python, emgucv, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to import Emgu.CV but failed.

environment:
Ubuntu 20.04,
pythonnet,
mono

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import clr
clr.AddReference('Emgu.CV')
from Emgu.CV import *
```

and then here is the error message:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019 from typeref (expected class 'System.Drawing.Size' in assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.get_method_info(intptr,System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetMethodInfo (System.IntPtr handle) [0x00000] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetDeclaringType (System.IntPtr handle) [0x00000] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_DeclaringType () [0x00000] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.GetClassInfo (System.Type type) [0x00035] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.InitClassBase (System.Type type, Python.Runtime.ClassBase impl) [0x00000] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.GetClass (System.Type type) [0x00028] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.GetAttribute (System.String name, System.Boolean guess) [0x0008e] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.GetAttribute (System.String name, System.Boolean guess) [0x00130] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.LoadNames () [0x00047] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ImportHook.__import__ (System.IntPtr self, System.IntPtr args, System.IntPtr kw) [0x00301] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Python.Runtime.ImportHook.__import__(intptr,intptr,intptr)
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019 from typeref (expected class 'System.Drawing.Size' in assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.get_method_info(intptr,System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetMethodInfo (System.IntPtr handle) [0x00000] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetDeclaringType (System.IntPtr handle) [0x00000] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_DeclaringType () [0x00000] in <a17fa1457c5d44f2885ac746c1764ea5>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.GetClassInfo (System.Type type) [0x00035] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.InitClassBase (System.Type type, Python.Runtime.ClassBase impl) [0x00000] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ClassManager.GetClass (System.Type type) [0x00028] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.GetAttribute (System.String name, System.Boolean guess) [0x0008e] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.GetAttribute (System.String name, System.Boolean guess) [0x00130] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ModuleObject.LoadNames () [0x00047] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at Python.Runtime.ImportHook.__import__ (System.IntPtr self, System.IntPtr args, System.IntPtr kw) [0x00301] in <5796c913ef894471b5861e1a904d8918>:0 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Python.Runtime.ImportHook.__import__(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to use EmguCV in Python? EmguCV is an OpenCV wrapper dedicated mainly to .NET. According to the [official documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Advantage_of_Emgu_CV) it

> can be used from several different languages, including C#, VB.NET, C++ and IronPython.

In Python you can use the directly OpenCV easily with the [unofficial pre-build (PyPI documentation)](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) or following the [official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html).

Comment: Oh! I see...I was trying to complete the code in Python, but the code was originally written in C#